# How to change Turtlebot 4 behavior when buttons are pressed?

Tags: ros-humble, turtlebot4

How can I modify what behavior the Turtlebot 4 exhibits when the Create buttons are pressed? I'm working through the tutorials which start with printing to console when a button is pressed. The printing behavior works, but the robot will also begin to drive when I press either of the two user buttons on the Create. How can I disable whatever is causing it to drive when I press these buttons?